# How to highlight a region over horizontal line?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a "dashed" highlight as in the photo:

[image]

So far, I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle,draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=.1cm, thick, fill=black, label={A}] (A) at  (-2,0) {};
    \node[circle,draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=.1cm, thick, fill=black, label={B}] (B) at  (0,0) {};
    \draw [] (A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the tikzlibrary `pattern` for the lines and set the option: `pattern=north east lines` for a `rectangle` drawn above the line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle,draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=.1cm, thick, fill=black, label={A}] (A) at  (-2,0) {};
    \node[circle,draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=.1cm, thick, fill=black, label={B}] (B) at  (0,0) {};
    \draw [] (A)--(B);
    \draw [pattern=north east lines, draw=none] ($(A)+(0,0.1)$) rectangle (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** Because this solution covers only horizontal and vertical lines, I thought about a better more general solution. I found the basis for this at [texample](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/oblique-incidence/).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    decorations.pathreplacing,
    decorations.pathmorphing
} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    linedecoration/.style={
        postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={border,angle=45,
                    amplitude=2mm,segment length=1.5mm}}},
    ]
    \node[circle,draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=.1cm, thick, fill=black, label={A}] (A) at  (-2,0) {};
    \node[circle,draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=.1cm, thick, fill=black, label={B}] (B) at  (1,1) {};
    \draw [linedecoration] (A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]